# OpenPGP smartcards compromised by blackhat 2015 simcard hack?

Tags: cryptography, smartcard, black-hat, side-channel

[This blackhat](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/08/06/researchers_crack_sim_card_aes128_encryption_in_10_minutes_for_cloning/) was a new sidechannel attack in the SIM-card AES encryption announced.

I am currently using the OpenPGP smart/SIM-card version 2.1 to store my PGP-private keys, which is the same model as the [EFF membership card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenPGP_card).

Does this disclosure mean, it's  possible to extract the private key from the chip?

Comment: GSM SIM cards are not related to BasicCards used by OpenPGP cards. (However it is not unlikely that many SD cards are suspectible to those differential attacks. You should never let an attacker physically get access to your card)